# How to get JSON object values for a Particular key

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am using JQGRId to get the grid data in JSON object format.

Result is something like :

```
{"Key":"value1"},{"Key":"value2", "id":"id"}
```

I need to get all the values into an array for "key".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{"Key":"value1"},{"Key":"value2", "id":"id"}];
var anArrayOfKeyValues = [];

arr.forEach(function(ob, i) {
  if("Key" in ob) anArrayOfKeyValues.push(ob.Key);
});

console.log(anArrayOfKeyValues); // ["value1", "value2"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roko. This is the solution I am looking for.