# Loop over array of objects, and generate new array by certain conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6

I have an Javascript object that looks like this:

```
const obj = [
{
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Me",
    "src": "/cool.jpg",
  }
},
{
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
},
{
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
},
{
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
}];
```

I need to loop over it and return an array that will look like:

```
const obj = [
  {
    name: "Ali",
    userID: 123,
    type: "photo",
    photos: [
      {
        title: "Me",
        src: "/cool.jpg"
      },
      {
        title: "Photo",
        src: "/photo.jpg"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    userID: 1234,
    type: "photo",
    photos: [
      {
        "title": "Me",
        "src": "photo.jpg"
      },
      {
        title: "Photo",
        src: "/photo.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note that the first object can contain an object with the same name over 100 times, I need it only once and inside an array of all of his photos.. How would I do that? What type of loop should i use? Thanks...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the array i am trying to achieve is totally different from this

Comment: yah... misread. Not totally but close. You actually want to merge `photo` of a user into multiple `photos` (which can be excerpt from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113265/how-to-get-json-object-values-for-a-particular-key/39113368#39113368)). What have you tried? You question as it stands shows no effort from your side. Do you have any code you already tried with a specific issue? Or you're trying to find someone to code this for you?

Comment: I have some code, but it's not doing exactly what i want, i need to stack those photos by the user id, i will add me code

Comment: Are wanting a new array of the data, or modifying the original `obj`?

Comment: @Xotic750 both are good for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another ES6 script:

```js
function merge(input) {
    return [...input.reduce( (acc, {name, userID, type, photo} ) => {
        let obj = acc.get(name) || {name, userID, type, photos: []};
        obj.photos.push(photo);
        return acc.set(name, obj);
    }, new Map()).values()];
}

// Sample data
var input = [{
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Me",
    "src": "/cool.jpg",
  }
},
{
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
},
{
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
},
{
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
}];

// convert
result = merge(input);

// output result
console.log(result);
```

#### Explanation:

[`input.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) iterates over the input, and accumulates a value that is initialised as a new Map (second argument to `reduce`).

In each iteration the accumulated value is passed as first argument, and the second argument receives the input element. By a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), we get variables for each of the `name`, `userID`, `type` and `photo` properties.

There are three statements executed in each iteration:

1. `obj` is defined either as the accumulated object we have for the `name` value, or (`||`) if we have none yet, as the given input element, but without the `photo` property and with a new `photos` array: `{name, userID, type, photos: []}`.
2. The current photo is added to it.
3. The resulting object is assigned back to the accumulated Map object, which itself is returned to the `reduce` internals. It will be passed as first argument for the next iteration, etc.

`reduce` returns the final accumulated object, i.e. a Map. As this is not the desired output format, it is converted to an array, which is done by taking its [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) (we don't need the keys any more), and converting that to an array with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (`[...  ]`).

Answer (score 1):

This does most of what you want:

```
var sorted = {};
obj.forEach(function(element){
  if(sorted[element.name]){
    sorted[element.name].photos.push(element.photo)
  }else{
    sorted[element.name] = {
      name: element.name,
      userID: element.userID,
      type: element.type,
      photos:[element.photo]
    }
  }
});
```

This doesn't create an array it creates a object with the names as keys.

```js
const obj = [
{
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Me",
    "src": "/cool.jpg",
  }
},
{
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
},
{
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
},
{
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
}];

var sorted = {};
obj.forEach(function(element){
  if(sorted[element.name]){
    sorted[element.name].photos.push(element.photo)
  }else{
    sorted[element.name] = {
      name: element.name,
      userID: element.userID,
      type: element.type,
      photos:[element.photo]
    }
  }
  console.log(sorted);
});


var sortedarray = sorted.map()
console.log(sortedarray);
```

You can add this bit of code to convert the object into an array:

```
var sortedarray = Object.keys(sorted).map(function(person){
return sorted[person]});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6 and creating a new object with a copy of the data and therefore leaving the original data intact.

1. Create a temporary Map.
2. Loop each entry in the object.
3. If the entry's ID does not exist in the Map then create and set a
   copy of the entry in the correct format.
4. If an entry already exists then just push a copy of the photos to the entry.
5. Return an array from the Map.

```js
function merge(obj) {
  const temp = new Map();
  for (let r of obj) {
    if (temp.has(r.userID)) {
      temp.get(r.userID).photos.push(Object.assign({}, r.photo));
    } else {
      const entry = Object.assign({}, r);
      entry.photos = [Object.assign({}, r.photo)];
      delete entry.photo;
      temp.set(r.userID, entry);
    }
  }
  return Array.from(temp, x => x[1]);
}

const obj = [{
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Me",
    "src": "/cool.jpg",
  }
}, {
  name: "Ali",
  userID: 123,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
}, {
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
}, {
  name: "John",
  userID: 1234,
  type: "photo",
  photo: {
    "title": "Photo",
    "src": "/photo.jpg"
  }
}];

const merged = merge(obj);
document.getElementById('out').textContent = JSON.stringify(merged, null, 2);
console.log(merged);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: This actually works in the way I need it to work except, I don't really understand how it works.. mind explaining? Thanks!

Comment: I've added a textual description of the workings, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to

- transform each user to the new user (with an array of photos)
- sort by the user's ID
- merge photos based on user's ID

In ES6

```
// Transform
let new_users = user.map(u => {
  let o = Object.assign({}, u, {photos: [u.photo]}));
  delete o.photo;
  return o;
});

// Sort by user ID
new_users = new_users.sort((a,b) => a.userID - b.userID);

// Merge on userID
let prev = null;
new_user = new_user.filter(u => {
  if (prev && prev.userID === u.userID) {
    prev.photos.push(u.photos[0]);
    return false;
  }
  prev = u;
  return true;
});
```